# Show data from two related tables

Tags: php, sql

I have this structure in my database:

table certificados -> id PK, title, description

table cert_gal ->id PK, id_certificados FK, file

The table certificates have title and description, the cert_galeria table, contains the images of each certificate. The cert_galeria table has the field id_certified as FK.

I want to display all the certificates and their respective gallery in the view, asking the query using join, I have the data in duplicate certificates, the title and description must be unique and show the corresponding image gallery.

I currently have this result:

```
2 => 
array (size=6)
  'titulo' => string 'teste' (length=5)
  0 => string 'teste' (length=5)
  'descricao' => string 'teste' (length=5)
  1 => string 'teste' (length=5)
  'arquivo' => string 'c45e41a73c02356cc3370caea4e37358.png' (length=36)
  2 => string 'c45e41a73c02356cc3370caea4e37358.png' 

3 => 
array (size=6)
  'titulo' => string 'teste' (length=5)
  0 => string 'teste' (length=5)
  'descricao' => string 'teste' (length=5)
  1 => string 'teste' (length=5)
  'arquivo' => string 'c29ecd046c6d90eb23eebd6d95ab3cff.png' (length=36)
  2 => string 'c29ecd046c6d90eb23eebd6d95ab3cff.png' (length=36)


4 => 
array (size=6)
  'titulo' => string 'teste' (length=5)
  0 => string 'teste' (length=5)
  'descricao' => string 'teste' (length=5)
  1 => string 'teste' (length=5)
  'arquivo' => string '471ed3267f3e342029523269083c3277.png' (length=36)
  2 => string '471ed3267f3e342029523269083c3277.png' (length=36)
```

my model:

```
public function getCertificados(){

    $sql = "SELECT certificados.titulo, certificados.descricao, cert_galeria.arquivo FROM certificados LEFT JOIN cert_galeria ON certificados.id = cert_galeria.id_certificado";

    $stmt = $this->pdo->prepare($sql);
    $stmt->execute();

    if($stmt->rowCount()>0):
        $dados = $stmt->fetchAll();
    endif;

    return $dados;

    var_dump($dados); die;

}
```

my controller:

```
class certificadosController extends Controller{

    public function index(){

    $data = array();
    $certificado = new Certificados;

    $dados['certificado'] = $certificado->getCertificados();


    $this->loadTemplate('certificados', $dados);

}
```

}

How can I display is correctly in my view without repeating the data (title, description) coming from the table certificates?

Comment: I think that you will need more than 1 query to achieve this.  You could  query the first table (certificados) and then for each row on that table fetch the related records from the second table.

Answer (score 0):

Solved the problem.

Models:

```
public function getCertificados(){

    $sql="SELECT id_certificado, titulo, descricao FROM certificados";

    $stmt = $this->pdo->prepare($sql);
    $stmt->execute();

    if($stmt->rowCount()>0):
        $dados = $stmt->fetchAll();
    endif;

    return $dados;

}

public function getImagesGal($id){


    $sql = "SELECT cert_galeria.id_certificado, cert_galeria.arquivo FROM cert_galeria right JOIN certificados ON cert_galeria.id_certificado = :id GROUP BY cert_galeria.arquivo";

    $stmt = $this->pdo->prepare($sql);
    $stmt->bindValue(":id", $id);
    $stmt->execute();

    if($stmt->rowCount()>0):
        $dados = $stmt->fetchAll();
    endif;

    return $dados;
}
```

Controller:

```
class certificadosController extends Controller{

    public function index(){

    $dados = array();
    $certificados = new Certificados();

    $dadosCert = $certificados->getCertificados();

    $lista = null;

    foreach ($dadosCert as $dadosC):

    $lista[$dadosC['titulo']] = ["id_certificado" => $certificados->getImagesGal($dadosC['id_certificado']), 'desc' => $dadosC['descricao']];

    endforeach;

    $dados['certificados'] = $lista;

    $this->loadTemplate('certificados', $dados);

}

}
```

View:

```
<?php foreach ($certificados as $cert => $value): ?>
<h2><?php echo $cert;?></h2>
<?php echo $value['desc']; ?>
<?php foreach($value['id_certificado'] as $arquivo): ?>
<?php echo $arquivo['arquivo']; ?>
<?php endforeach; ?>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```